# Javascript show/hide randomly not working

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I am using this javascript/jquery to hide a part of my page and show a new part. It was working yesterday, and then I came on today and its not working. I did some editing such as adding a "snowing" javascript, and a javascript code that changes the bg color on the click of a button, but I removed everything I changed, and it still doesn't work... Here is my whole code...

```
<html><head>

     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Hides something then shows something. -->
function friedrice(id, id2) {
     $('#' + id).hide(); 
     $('#' + id2).show(); 

}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Show stuff with fade in -->
    function showStuff(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
object = document.getElementById(id)

$(object).hide();
        $(object).fadeIn(1000);
    }
</script>




<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Hides hidden stuff on load -->

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#swf').hide(); 
    $('#surprise').hide();
}); 

</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Shows stuff -->
function katana(id) {
     $('#' + id).show();

}
</script>


<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Popup on exit -->
function box()
{
var r=confirm("Content") 
if (r==true)
  {
  window.location.href="russia.html";
  }
else
  {
  window.location.href="china.html";
  }
}
</script>


</head>
    <body onunload="box()";
    <div id="chopsticks"> <!-- This is the "main" content that is displayed before the last checkbox is checked -->
    <OBJECT id="swf" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:20%; left:15%;" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="90%" HEIGHT="70%" id="rice" ALIGN=""><PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="rice.swf"><PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=low><EMBED src="rice.swf" quality=low bgcolor=#EEEEEE WIDTH="90%" HEIGHT="90%" NAME="rice" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED> </OBJECT>

<center><h1>Logo Here!</h1><br>
</center>
                    <span id="a1" style="display: block;"><div class="texts" >
                                    <div class="title" >
                    <strong>Step 1</strong><br><br>
                </div>

<div class="rice">Content<br></div>
<label class="label_check" >
    <input name="sample_check1" id="sample_check1" value="1" type="radio" onclick="showStuff('a2')"  />
Done?
    </label></div></span>
<br>
                    <span id="a2" style="display: none;"><div class="texts">

                                    <div class="title" >
                    <strong>Step 2</strong><br><br>
                </div>

<div class="rice">Content<br></div>
<label class="label_check" >
    <input name="sample_check2" id="sample_check2" value="1" type="radio" onclick="showStuff('a3');" />
Done?
    </label>
                </div></span>
<br>
                    <span id="a3" style="display: none;"><div class="texts">

                                    <div class="title" >
                    <strong>Step 3</strong><br><br>
                </div>
                    <div class="rice">Content<br></div>
<label class="label_check" >
    <input name="sample_check3" id="sample_check3" value="1" type="radio" onclick="showStuff('stage');setTimeout(katana, 10000, 'swf');setTimeout(friedrice, 12000, 'chopsticks', 'surprise');" /> <!-- The showStuff function will show an image with a fade in. The katana function will show the swf, then 2 seconds later, the "friedrice" function will remove all of the the content on the page including the swf and show new "surprise" content. -->
Ready?
    </label>
                </div></span>

        <span id="stage" style="display:none;">
            <img src="images/dot.png" style=" position:absolute; left:44%; top:20%;"/>
        </span>


                    <script>
        $('body').hide();
        $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    </script>
</div>
<div id="surprise"> <!-- This is the "hidden" content that is displayed 12 seconds after the checkbox is checked -->
<center>
<p> i jo</p>
<embed src="scare.mp3" autoplay="true" loop="true" height="240" width="100" /></embed>
</div>
</center>
</body></html>
```

This is without the css, as I thought it was not necessary. The important parts are commented. Please excuse the sloppiness and the names of variables, functions etc. I usually don't give my code out xD. But I have no idea what happened, I changed everything back that I changed. Hope someone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? Sometimes scripts are cached and it doesn't update with the new code until you flush the cache. This has happened to be before and after I cleared the cache in my browser (Firefox) it started working again.

Comment: @Ishikawa Yep, I tried multiple browser, cleared cache, even multiple computers. There must be some lingering code in there from when I was changing stuff. I really don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's a `;` missing after `object = document.getElementById(id)`:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Show stuff with fade in -->
   function showStuff(id) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
      object = document.getElementById(id);
                                //this one^
      $(object).hide();
      $(object).fadeIn(1000);
}
</script>
```

var `r=confirm("Content")` is also missing a `;` at the Popup on exit part

Comment: Yup I just saw that too. That's definitely breaking the code. See if it works after you add that semicolon.

Comment: I fixed that, nothing changed. Cleared cache also :(

Comment: `var r=confirm("Content")` is also missing a `;` at the Popup on exit part

Comment: That one was actually there, I just missed it while copy/pasting

Comment: The script is working on my pc. If you're using chrome, try pressing ctrl+shift+j to show the javascript console and see if it shows any errors.

Comment: No errors, are you sure its showing the embedded music? and the "i jo" text

Answer (score 0):

Try going in to your browsers settings and clearing the cache, this might help out.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed some of your code and now I do not receive errormessage:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page title</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Hides something then shows something. -->
function friedrice(id, id2) {
     $('#' + id).hide(); 
     $('#' + id2).show(); 
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Show stuff with fade in -->
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    object = document.getElementById(id)

    $(object).hide();
        $(object).fadeIn(1000);
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Hides hidden stuff on load -->
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#swf').hide(); 
    $('#surprise').hide();
}); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> <!-- Shows stuff -->
function katana(id) {
    $('#' + id).show();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function box(){ 
    var r = window.confirm("Content");
    if(r==true){
        window.location.href="russia.html";
    }
    else{
        window.location.href="china.html";
    }
}
</script>

</head>
    <body onUnload="box">
    <div id="chopsticks"> <!-- This is the "main" content that is displayed before the last checkbox is checked -->
    <OBJECT id="swf" style="z-index:2; position:absolute; top:20%; left:15%;" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" WIDTH="90%" HEIGHT="70%" id="rice" ALIGN=""><PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="rice.swf"><PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=low><EMBED src="rice.swf" quality=low bgcolor=#EEEEEE WIDTH="90%" HEIGHT="90%" NAME="rice" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"></EMBED> </OBJECT>

<center><h1>Logo Here!</h1><br>
</center>
                    <span id="a1" style="display: block;"><div class="texts" >
                                    <div class="title" >
                    <strong>Step 1</strong><br><br>
                </div>

<div class="rice">Content<br></div>
<label class="label_check" >
    <input name="sample_check1" id="sample_check1" value="1" type="radio" onclick="showStuff('a2')"  />
Done?
    </label></div></span>
<br>
                    <span id="a2" style="display: none;"><div class="texts">

                                    <div class="title" >
                    <strong>Step 2</strong><br><br>
                </div>

<div class="rice">Content<br></div>
<label class="label_check" >
    <input name="sample_check2" id="sample_check2" value="1" type="radio" onclick="showStuff('a3');" />
Done?
    </label>
                </div></span>
<br>
                    <span id="a3" style="display: none;"><div class="texts">

                                    <div class="title" >
                    <strong>Step 3</strong><br><br>
                </div>
                    <div class="rice">Content<br></div>
<label class="label_check" >
    <input name="sample_check3" id="sample_check3" value="1" type="radio" onclick="showStuff('stage');setTimeout(katana, 10000, 'swf');setTimeout(friedrice, 12000, 'chopsticks', 'surprise');" /> 
Ready?
    </label>
                </div></span>

        <span id="stage" style="display:none;">
            <img src="images/dot.png" style=" position:absolute; left:44%; top:20%;"/>
        </span>


                    <script>
        $('body').hide();
        $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    </script>
</div>
<div id="surprise"> <!-- This is the "hidden" content that is displayed 12 seconds after the checkbox is checked -->
<center>
<p> i jo</p>
<embed src="scare.mp3" autoplay="true" loop="true" height="240" width="100"></embed>
</div>
</center>
</body></html>
```